# Login screen password not working in MacOS bigsur. how to fix it?

Tags: macos, authentication, passwords, macos-big-sur

While I start mac-mini. I was unable to login into the login screen. It shows the wrong password.
but the password is right and I daily use it.

CPU: Mac mini
OS: Big Sur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Research and find the solution from the Apple support team. and I saw many people face this problem.

**Solution:**

**Step 1:**

Start on your Mac and continue to long press and hold the power button until you see the startup options window. Click the gear/settings icon labeled Options, then click Continue.

Note: If you're asked to select a user you know the password for, select the user, click Next and enter their administrator password.

**Step 2:**

Then select reinstall macOS from the utility window in macOS recovery, then click Continue and follow the onscreen instructions.

Follow these guidelines during installation:

- If the installer asks to unlock your disk, enter the password you use to log in to your Mac.
- If the installer can't see your disk or notifies you that it can't install macOS on your computer or volume, you may need to erase your disk first.
- If the installer offers you the choice between installing on Macintosh HD or Macintosh HD – Data, choose Macintosh HD.
- Allow the installation to complete without putting your Mac to sleep or closing its lid. Your Mac may restart and show a progress bar several times, and the screen may be empty for minutes at a time.

When the installation is complete, your Mac may restart to a setup assistant.

For More information: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204904